# Nested loop printing multiple " " on each line instead of one " " on each line

Tags: nested-loops

I am having some trouble understanding why the following code prints for example:

[image]

In my head, I am thinking that it would print something like:

[image]

with one hashmark on each line.

It seems like the counter is starting over at 0 every time in the inner loop and then checking the condition each time through the updated value, instead of starting at the updated value and checking the condition.

Btw, I do want it to print out what it does, I just don't understand the logic behind what it does. I thought "variable++" was to update the variable then check the condition.

If you can help, thanks!!!

Here is the code:

```
 int main(void)

{
   int h; 
   int c;
   int w;
   do
  {
    h = get_int("Positive integer: ");
  }
    while (h < 1 || h > 8);

for (c = 0; c < h; c++)
{     
    for (w = 0; w <=c; w++)
    {
        printf("#");
    }
    printf("\n");
```

Comment: The first loop is executing the nested loop first before printing ```\n``` which leads to multiple prints in one line. You could modify it to print ```printf("#\n")``` in the nested loop. Other than that - with nested loops it is easiest to understand them by making them print the indices, e.g. with ```printf("%d %d", w,c);``` should show you how the loops work.

Answer (score 0):

In the inner Loop, each time c changes value, w is defined as 0 again.

First Outer Loop: c= 0

---

```
1stInnerLoop:    w = 0 -> is w<= c ? -> yes -> printf #
```

Second Outer Loop: c = 1

---

```
1stInnerLoop:    w = 0 -> (is w<= c ?) -> yes printf #
2ndInnerLoop:    w = 1 -> (is w<= c ?) -> yes printf #
```

Third Outer Loop: c = 2

---

```
1stInnerLoop:    w = 0 -> (is w<= c ?) -> yes printf #
2ndInnerLoop:    w = 1 -> (is w<= c ?) -> yes printf #
3rdInnerLoop:    w = 2 -> (is w<= c ?) -> yes printf #
```

And so on...

Comment: "In the inner Loop, each time c changes value, w is defined as 0 again." Okay, this is what I didn't know. Thank you so much!